# C Language: Exclusive calls of a function

Tags: c

I wondered if its possible that you can declare method A in a way that only a specific other method B can call A.

The reason beeing is that i want to restrict one method from beeing called from main (because of strange testing algorithms at college). If main called this method (which is an helper method), the whole programm would be trash.

So, how can i "forbid" main (or any other method) to call my dangerous method B ?

Comment: Make it static to a particular file

Comment: Making it static is certainly a good step, possibly the best one. Something else to consider though: why would having it called by `main()` be so disruptive? The normal answer to this would be that needed data may not have been initialized - so another option is to simply detect that condition and return an appropriate error.

Comment: What about simply `#define dangerous_method something_thats_not_defined` in a header.  And then when you want to use it, `#undef`.

Comment: Even if the function is `static`, it's possible that some other function in the same translation unit could take its address and make it available. You can make it difficult or inconvenient to call a function; you can't really make it impossible.

Comment: @KeithThompson Depending on the architecture, the compiler is allowed to  take some "shortcuts", like using specific addressing modes or "short branches" and "short returns" that can make it really pretty impossible to call the `static` function from outside, even if you would know the address. Another one: A compiler doesn't even need to make a `static` function a function at all. it is free to inline it into any caller, which makes it even more difficult to call it from outside - it's got no address.

Comment: @tofro though if you take the address of a static function, the compiler couldn't optimise out the function - it would exist even if never actually called and made inline.

Comment: This is all kind of academic. If you had access to the source file to change it (or, take the address of the `static` function), it would be way easier to remove the `static`and recompile. I seem to be missing the point here.

Comment: @tofro in response to KeithThompson's comment, whose point was you can take the address of a static function; you said that it may not have an address as it may not exist, but if you take its address, it will of course always have one.

Comment: Yep, that's right. But still academic ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put *a* and *b* into a separate compilation unit (object file of its own). Declare *a* `static` to that compilation unit, make *b* globally visible, and also known in a specific header file.

Anything *outside* that compilation unit will not be able to call (or even "see") *a*, while *b* is fully visible for the rest of your program and very well able to call *a*.

If you want to make sure that nobody is able to change this, distribute only the compiled .o file and an appropriate header.

b.c:

```
static int a(int i){
   ...
}

int b(int x){
  return a(x + 100);
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "b.h"
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
   int c, d;

   c = b(100);     /* works */
   d = a(100);     /* will not compile */
}
```

Comment: this actaully solved my problem. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

How about using backtrace and backtrace_symbol functions. [backtrace man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html)

So inside this function A() check if it is called by specific allowed function and then only proceed or return (return with error or exit if needed).

Note: This method does not avoid getting your program instruction pointer (program counter) inside the dangerous function A (even when called from unwanted main()).

Comment: Good idea, thus +1. Not very portable, thus -1. Basically only works on Linux and/or gcc

Comment: this idea is actually good and i appreciate it beeing shared! +1 thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check this at run time, you can use `backtrace` or similar function to determine who invoked your method. Be aware that the symbol names may be unavailable without the use of special linker options.

Comment: `backtrace` is not a C language feature.

Comment: @Jens That is true. `backtrace` and others are GNU extensions. However, you can use `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` on Windows platform.